# Sequelize MySql Insert: Node js vs Django

Tags: mysql, sql, django, sequelize.js

DB inserts from Sequelize take minimum thrice the time as compared to inserts by Django. Sometimes node is around 8- 10 times slower than python. (According to newrelic)
The SQL fired by Django: **Time ~2ms**

```
  INSERT INTO `table` (`created_on`, `updated_on`, `field2`, `field3`, `field1`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`, `field7`, `fiedl8`) VALUES ('2016-11-03 14:52:31', '2016-11-03 14:52:31', NULL, NULL, 100617299, '68.00', '75.00', '75.00', 0, '1.00')
```

The SQL fired by Node: **Time ~20ms**

```
  INSERT INTO `table` (`id`,`field`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`,`field6`,`field7`,`field8`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'68.00','75.00','75.00',0,1,'2016-11-03 09:46:05','2016-11-03 09:46:05',100617299)
```

I have tried increasing the number of number of connection from Node but it did not help.